# decltype of iterator as template argument

Tags: c++, c++11

Below is a simplified code to replicate my problem:

**Working code:**

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    std::vector<int> x;
    std::map<char, std::vector<int>::size_type> y;
    y[0]=x.size();
    return 0;
}
```

**Not working code** (using decltype):

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    std::vector<int> x;
    //std::map<char, std::vector<int>::size_type> y;
    std::map<char, decltype(x.begin())> y;
    y[0]=x.size();
    return 0;
}
```

The code fails to compile with the following error:

*error: no match for ‘operator=’ (operand types are ‘std::map > >::mapped_type {aka __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator >}’ and ‘std::vector::size_type {aka long unsigned int}’)
     y[0]=x.size();*

Shouldn't `decltype(x.begin())` be equivalent to `std::vector<int>::size_type`?

Comment: `x.begin()` is an iterator and `x.size()` isnt, so no, they are not equivalent

Comment: You do know that [`begin`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/begin) returns an *iterator* and not an integer which is what [`size`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/size) returns? Perhaps you should take a few steps back and [find a good beginners book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) and start over?

Comment: would be really interesting to know why you think they are equivalent. I mean already your title says that it is an iterator...

Comment: Looking at some reference for [`begin`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/begin) and [`size`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/size) would have told you their return types differ.

Comment: @tobi303 I guess I was used to do stuff like  `it - vec.begin()` to get the current index the iterator is pointing to. I guess some implicit casting is happening here

Comment: @JafarQutteineh no, there is no implicit casting, it is just that `iterator::operator-` typically returns an integer, but iterators themself arent integers

Comment: @tobi303 Thanks, it's very clear now!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Shouldn't `decltype(x.begin())` be equivalent to `std::vector<int>::size_type`?

No, what [std::vector::begin](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/begin) returns is `std::vector<T>::iterator`.

I suppose what you want would be `decltype(x.size())`.

Comment: My bad! I was looking at some think like `it- vec.begin()' and I assumed they both refer internally to the same type